# Savings Bank Account in India - Need to convert to NRO

Tags: india, banking, savings, non-resident

I have a Savings Bank Account in India. I have moved to Australia.

Can I convert this account into an NRO account. What documents do I have to submit?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I convert this account into an NRO account.

There is no "Can I". One must convert any ordinary savings account to an NRO as per regulation.

> What documents do I have to submit?

An evidence that your status is / will be NRI. The exact documents would be advised by your Bank. Generally an employment visa in other country, appointment letter or passport showing stamping etc are sufficient proof along with a letter from you requesting a change.

This can also be done remotely. Write to your bank to understand the process.